# Cordova app having problems with WSS but not HTTPS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am suddenly facing issues with making Secure WebSockets work with my cordova/ionic-v1 app. By suddenly, I mean it worked fine till a month ago. I did not test this feature for a while, till users starting posting about errors recently.  Over the last month, upgraded IOS to 10.2.1, also updated Cordova from 5.x to 6.

**The gist of the problem is my app is working with a self-signed server over HTTPS. That works just fine. It's just that WSS doesn't work (WS works fine). So its not a global SSL issue, just with WSS.**

The error I get when I open a web socket:

`CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9807)`

My CSP in `index.html` (I know it is permissive, I'm trying to get everything to work, and will then remove extraneous stuff)

```
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * blob: 
android-webview-video-poster: cdvphotolibrary:  'self' data: ws: wss:; default-
src * blob: 'self' gap: wss: ws: data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src * http: https: ws: wss:;">
```

My config.xml:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="mailto:*" />
    <access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' minimum-tls-version='TLSv1.0' requires-forward-secrecy='false' requires-certificate-transparency='false'/>
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Cordova Version:

```
Cordova 6.5.0
Installed platforms:
  android 5.1.1
  ios 4.3.1
```

Can anyone spot any issues? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I don't know why, but for WSS to work with certificates that are self-signed on IOS 10.2, I had to import the self signed certificate to my phone and install it. This is very odd, as I did not have to do it for HTTPs connections to the same server (using the same certs). Go figure.